# How to inject dependency to factory with arguments from Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a Web API project with the following packages installed:

- Ninject
- Ninject.Extensions.Factory
- Ninject.MVC5
- Ninject.Web.Common (and WebHost)
- Ninject.Web.WebApi (and WebHost)

I'm trying to inject with arguments from the Http method.  One of the dependencies, itself, **depends** on another dependency that also needs Http method's arguments.  How can I structure this?  I am getting the "Make sure your Controller has parameterless" error when the endpoint is accessed.

```
public interface IFooFactory {
    Foo.Foo Create(string arg1, IBar barService);
}

public class FooFactory : IFooFactory {
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public FooFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot) {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    // Need dependency injected here... How? barService also needs http args
    public Foo.Foo Create(string arg1, IBarService barService) {
        return resolutionRoot.Get<Foo.Foo>(
            new ConstructorArgument("arg1", arg1),
            new CosntructorArgument("barService", barService)
            );
    }
}
```

In this case `IBarService barService` needs to be injected into `FooFactory` and `IBarService` needs to be instantiated with Http arguments.  I just don't know how to structure this.  Do I need to make another factory?

This is my **NinjectWebCommon.cs**:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
    kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>()
        .To<FooFactory>()
        .InRequestScope();

    // add a bar factory?
    kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>()
        .To<BarFactory>()
        .InRequestScope();
}
```

If I add a `IBarFactory barFactory`, how can I pass it along to `FooFactory`?

I made another factory for `IBarService`, passing it arguments from Http:

**Second Factory**

```
public interface IBarFactory
{
    BarService.BarService Create(string arg1);
}

public class BarFactory : IBarFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public BarFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public BarService Create(string arg1)
    {
        return resolutionRoot.Get<BarService>(
            new ConstructorArgument("arg1", arg1));
    }
}
```

**How HTTP args are consumed**

```
public FooFooController : ApiController {

    private readonly IFooFactory fooFactory;
    private readonly IBarFactory barFactory;

    public FooFooController(IFooFactory fooFactory, IBarFactory barFactory) {
        this.fooFactory = fooFactory;
        this.barFactory = barFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Post(string arg1) {
        // arguments are consumed here
        var barService = this.barFactory.Create(arg1);
        var fooService = this.fooFactory.Create(arg1, barService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the logic used to retrieve the "HTTP arguments"?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit See edit

Comment: You've got all the parts.. but Ninject seems to be set-up incorrectly. That's why you've got the `Make sure your Controller has a parameterless Constructor` message. That shouldn't occur when Ninject is set-up correctly to resolve the dependencies. If Ninject then can't resolve a type it will throw a different exception. So it's not about your bindings, it's about how Ninject is integrated into your project.